# Extending a React component and using the same method in the base component and the new component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, composition, react-table

When you extend a React component using composition, I'm not sure how to manage methods at multiple levels. Have a component that uses the method getTrProps to then apply styling for all instances of that component that we use. That gets applied for the extended component. But at the individual level it also needs getTrProps to add click handlers, and at the moment neither of them are run.

This comes from needing to apply the same styling code to every react-table we use but not wanting to include it every single time. To set the row height to always be 40px for example, you need to use getTrProps so extended-react-table calls this.normal Rows as shown below.  However when you use this extended-react-table you need to set a row click event which you do by using getTrProps={this.rows}.  It's the same method property which is what is causing an issue.

Extended-react-table (the extended version of react-table) itself has:

```js
getTrProps={this.setRowDefaultsForAllReactTables} and then:
setRowDefaultsForAllReactTables= (state, rowInfo, column) => {
return { style: { height:40, display:'flex', alignItems: 'center'} }
}
```

with this code only being written once. 
While the usage of extended-react-table has:

```js
getTrProps={this.addRowEvents}  and then:
addRowEvents= (state, rowInfo) => {
    return {   onClick: e => { this.props.openProduct(rowInfo.original); }  
}
```

With this code being written for every instance of extended-react-table (and is always different as the onClick events required are always different).

Clearly they interfere with each other. What means should I be using to ensure that the events run at both levels? Or do I need to combine the props rather than have it run at both levels? So this.setRowDefaultsForAllReactTables combined somehow with this.props.getTrProps?

This is a standard case of having lots of boiler plate code over maybe 200 instances of the same component and not wanting to have to write it every time so you create a new component with all the common code in it so that you get all the default settings then in each instance you add anything that is specific to just that instance.  So common row styling is in one place but row click events are in many places.  The problem is there are two sets of thing to run but only one method. Here is the entire code for extended-react-table:

```js
import * as React from 'react'
import ReactTable, {TableProps} from "react-table"
import './../components/ext-react-table.css'
import { Paper } from '@material-ui/core';
import Pagination from './pagination';

export interface IExtendedReactTableProps{
}

export interface IExtendedReactTableState {
}

export class ExtendedReactTable extends React.Component<IExtendedReactTableProps & 
Partial<TableProps>, IExtendedReactTableState> {
    constructor(props: IExtendedReactTableProps & Partial<TableProps>) {
        super(props);
    }

setDefaultSettingsForRows = (state, rowInfo, column) => {
    return {  
        style: { height:40, display:'flex', alignItems: 'center'},
    }
}

setDefaultSettingsForHeaderRows = (state, rowInfo, column) => {
    return {
        style: { height: 40, display:'flex', alignItems: 'center', 
outline:'none'
    }
}

render() {
  return(
  <Paper>
  <ReactTable {...this.props} style={{cursor:'pointer', fontSize: 13, 
background:'#fff', borderLeft: 0, borderRight: 0}} PaginationComponent= 
  {Pagination}
          getTrProps={this.setDefaultSettingsForRows} getTheadThProps= 
  {this.setDefaultSettingsForHeaderRows} />
 </Paper>)
}
}
```

And sample instance of its usage:

```js
 <ExtendedReactTable data={products} columns={[ {Header: "Product", accessor: "ProductName"}]}
      defaultSorted={[ { id: "ProductName",  asc: true }]}
      defaultPageSize={10} className={" -highlight"} 
      getTrProps={this.addRowEvents}  />
```

Currently neither or this.addRowEvents or this.setDefaultSettingsForHeaderRows run.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking.

Comment: It's difficult to decipher what you're trying to do. Can you possibly edit your question to identify what you're trying to do? You want to call `getTrProps` and have it use *your* event handler and not the library's built-in event handler?

Comment: Hi, hopefully the issue is more clear now?  Have changed the method names  to make the intent clearer too.  I probably have the wrong approach as I can't see how to do something that fits the composition paradigm but essentially I'd want it to run both this.setRowDefaultsForAllReactTables for every single extended-react-table and if applicable run addRowEvents whenever an individual instance needs to set a row click event.  The issue is that both need to use getTrProps

Comment: @MarkC I want to get it to run both my event handler and the in-built one.  Don't know how to combine the two

Comment: I don't know what `extended-react-table` is, but if it's composited, then can access the composited class's functions by calling them as you would call any other method. If it's inherited, there's `super`, like any other class.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm extending a component called react-table, with the new component being called extended-react-table.  I have used composition not inheritance because that's the proper usage in React but I have no idea how to get it to run something for each row for each extended-react-table instance when extended-react-table is already using that method prop to set the row defaults. There must be some standard way of doing this using composition?

Comment: @DaveNewton extended-react-table contains <ReactTable .... getTrProps={this.setDefaultSettingsForRows}/>  while a sample page might include <ExtendedReactTable ... getTrProps={this.addRowEvents}/>  So "calling them as you would any other method" (getTrProps={this.addRowEvents}) doesn't work - no row events are ever fired

Comment: I have no idea how to answer this the way you're asking it. You need to provide more context, in the question, showing how you're using both components, where the methods you're talking about are defined, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton I've added loads more but I don't know what else you want.  I've specified the methods -> getTrProps={this.setRowDefaultsForAllReactTables} in the composited component and getTrProps={this.addRowEvents} for each instance where it is used

Comment: Inside `ExtendedReactTable` you need to run both the function you pass in to its `getTrProps` property, and the one you specify for `ReactTable`. I don't understand why you can't call them both; you have both references. The trivial solution is to create a function in `ExtendedReactTable#render` that calls both, and pass that new function to `ReactTable#getTrProps`. If the table is rendering a lot you might want to cache it or something, but that's a separate issue. So you're calling them as you would any other method.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm sorry I really clearly don't understand.  I don't know how I have both references, at least not in the same place.  Are you able to explain please?

Comment: @DaveNewton I don't know how ExternalReactTable could call the method from the page where it's used as it doesn't know what it is.  It would find out what it is through getTrProps but you're saying I need to put a new function name into there instead so I have no idea what to try.

Comment: `<ReactTable ... getTrProps={() => { this.props.getTrProps(); this.setDefaultSettingsForRows() }} ... />`

Comment: @DaveNewton, thanks but that won't work because it expects a function name, not the results of a function. Remember I was using getTrProps={this.setDefaultSettingsForRows} not getTrProps={this.setDefaultSettingsForRows()} The function is meant to return properties (that's why they call it getTrProps) but needs to be a function not its results. If I could pass setDefaultSettingsForRows & give it an extra parameter (this.props.getTrProps) then I could potentially combine the two result sets in that function and return them. Is that approach workable? I'm not sure how to pass the extra parameter

Comment: This is the code that gets run in the react-table source: const trProps = _.splitProps(getTrProps(finalState, rowInfo, undefined, this)) so not really sure how to do this without changing the source code for react-table.  This all seems astonishingly difficult to do with composition while it would be completely simple with inheritance (obviously there are other very sound reasons not to use inheritance)

Comment: That isn't the result of a function, it's a function, save as what you're doing now, just an anonymous one..

Comment: @DaveNewton, I'm talking about the function itself - it meant to return a function name but when you run this.props.getTrProps() and this.setDefaultSettingsForRows() you are returning the results of two functions -  the () means you get the results of them.  So it fails for that reason.

Comment: this.setDefaultSettingsForRows and this.setDefaultSettingsForRows() are very different, it expects a this.setDefaultSettingsForRows but your code is trying to pass it two this.setDefaultSettingsForRows()s

Comment: No. It is a function that calls both functions, just like you asked for. You might want to brush up on your JS, specifically function references. For example, passing the reference 'someFunction' is identical to passing '() => someFunction()', which is a reference to an anonymous function.

Comment: Yes but that isn't what we are talking about.  Your code was () => {someFunction(); someFunction2();} which doesn't work when the functions return properties like I mentioned, right? I have tried to combine the properties from each, let properties = someFunction(); and then combine with the results of someFunction2() and return the combined properties.  However for some reason this.setDefaultSettingsForRows(state,rowInfo,column, instance) works but this.props.getTrProps(state, rowInfo, column, instance) gives a Typescript error "Type 'ComponentPropsGetter0' has no compatible call signatures"

Comment: No clue about the TypeScript issues; probably an issue compositing return types if they're different for the two function, but don't know enough typescript to help. And didn't see the TS code edit. But I'll tag it properly since your issue appears to be solely typescript related.